# The easiest way to build enterprise .ipa using default distribution certificate in command line

Tags: xcode, enterprise

What is The easiest way build enterprise .ipa using default distribution certificate in command line?

I try to build in next way:

> xcodebuild archive
>
> === BUILD NATIVE TARGET MyProject OF PROJECT MyProject WITH THE DEFAULT
>   CONFIGURATION (Release) === Check
>   dependencies unsupported build action
>   'archive'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>     Check dependencies

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution. Here is the easiest way how to do it:

> /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos
>   PackageApplication -v MyProject.app -o
>   /Users/user/Desktop/MyProject.ipa
>   --sign "iPhone Distribution: My Company LLC" --embed
>   "My_Company_Ad_Hoc.mobileprovision"

My_Company_Ad_Hoc.mobileprovision should be placed near MyProject.app (in this case)